# Finding the second latest date in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have two columns:

GRP_ACCT_NO, TRANS_DATE

Data is about the transactions made by different accounts. So, GRP_ACCT_NO has recurring values and the TRANS_DATE gives the date, that particular account made a transaction on. I have about 1.5 million records in the data set but only 97k unique accounts. I want to find the second latest transaction date for each Account in SAS

Here is the code which I tried:

```
proc sql;
  create table second_latest_trans as
  select GRP_ACCT_NO,Max(TRANS_DATE) from project.spend as ps
  where TRANS_DATE < (select max(TRANS_DATE) 
                      from project.spend as ps2 
                      where ps.GRP_ACCT_NO = ps2.GRP_ACCT_NO 
                      group by GRP_ACCT_NO)
  group by GRP_ACCT_NO;
quit;
```

The code doesn't seem to get any results. Its taking a long time to load.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has no concept of order of observations. Use a DATA step.  If your data is not already sorted then sort it (create an index).

If you just want the second record, even if there are ties then you can just count the records for each account.

```
data second_latest_trans;
  set project.spend;
  by GRP_ACCT_NO TRANS_DATE;
  if first.grp_acct then recno=0;
  recno+1;
  if recno=2 then output;
run;
```

If there are multiple records for the same value of TRANS_DATE and you want the second distinct value of TRANS_DATE then this more complicated step would work.

```
data second_latest_trans;
  set project.spend;
  by GRP_ACCT_NO TRANS_DATE;
  if first.grp_acct then found=0;
  else if not found and first.trans_date then do;
     output;
     found=1;
  end;
  retain found;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I think my question was not clear. I have rephrased it now. What I want is the account number along with their second latest transaction. So, basically, my new data set should have about 97k records. When I tried the above code, I am getting 1.3 million records.

Answer (score 1):

Your query (apart from the formatting) looks reasonable.  I wonder if the `group by` in the subquery is throwing things off.  Try this version:

```
proc sql;
create table second_latest_trans as
    Select GRP_ACCT_NO, Max(TRANS_DATE)
    from project.spend ps
    where TRANS_DATE < (SELECT max(ps2.TRANS_DATE)
                        from project.spend ps2
                        where ps.GRP_ACCT_NO = ps2.GRP_ACCT_NO
                       )
   group by GRP_ACCT_NO;
quit;
```

If you want this to run faster, you want an index on `project.spend(GRP_ACCT_NO, TRANS_DATE)`.  The data step solution (proposed in another answer) would probably be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

SAS SQL is not good tool to handle sequence issue. If you want to find the second top or low record in group, maybe you could try this. I use class as example to find second weight person in each group. The method is to drop top weight person from group first, then select top weight person, however, it could handle tie weight. Hope to give you some idea.

```
proc sql;
  select * from (select * from sashelp.class where weight not in 
  (select weight from sashelp.class group by age having weight=max(weight))) 
  group by age having weight=max(weight);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data test;
set spend;
run;
```

sort by acct_no so the largest date is on top.

```
proc sort data=test;
by grp_acct_no trans_date descending;
run;
```

remove the record(s) that correspond to the latest date

```
data test2;
set test;
by grp_acct_no trans_date;
if first.grp_acct_no =1  and first.trans_date =1  then delete;
run;
```

Now the first record corresponding to each acct_no is the second largest date because the largest one is removed. delete everything except this record.

```
data test3;
set test2;
by grp_acct_no trans_date;
if Not (first.grp_acct_no =1  and first.trans_date =1 ) then delete;

run;
```

test3 is the final dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single pass through the data using a `retain` :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by GRP_ACCT_NO TRANS_DATE ;

  retain T1 T2 . ;
  if first.GRP_ACCT_NO then call missing(T1,T2) ;

  if TRANS_DATE > T1 then do ;
    T2 = T1 ;
    T1 = TRANS_DATE ;
  end ;

  if last.GRP_ACCT_NO ;

  format T1 T2 date9. ;
run ;
```

`T1` is the latest TRANS_DATE, `T2` is the previous one to that.